# XRDP on ARM64 bullseye issue

Tags: pi-4, 64-bit, xrdp

On the newest PI OS bullseye (not beta!) I installed the **xrdp** and added user xrdp to the ssl-cert group. When I open the RDP session on w10 PC and try to log to PI4 I get an error saying:

```
connecting to sesman ip 127.0.0.1 port 3350 
sesman connect ok sending
login info to session manager, please wait... 
login succesful for display 11 
started connecting connection problem, giving up 
some problem
```

When I checked the status of the xrdp service it shows that the service is started and running, but it shows some errors:

```
Feb 06 12:36:10 pi4-8 xrdp[191346]: [INFO ] Socket 12: AF_INET6 connection received from ::ffff:82.208.181.53 port 52965
Feb 06 12:36:10 pi4-8 xrdp[394313]: [INFO ] Using default X.509 certificate: /etc/xrdp/cert.pem
Feb 06 12:36:10 pi4-8 xrdp[394313]: [INFO ] Using default X.509 key file: /etc/xrdp/key.pem
Feb 06 12:36:10 pi4-8 xrdp[394313]: [ERROR] SSL_accept: I/O error
Feb 06 12:36:10 pi4-8 xrdp[394313]: [ERROR] trans_set_tls_mode: ssl_tls_accept failed
Feb 06 12:36:10 pi4-8 xrdp[394313]: [ERROR] xrdp_sec_incoming: trans_set_tls_mode failed
Feb 06 12:36:10 pi4-8 xrdp[394313]: [ERROR] xrdp_rdp_incoming: xrdp_sec_incoming failed
Feb 06 12:36:10 pi4-8 xrdp[394313]: [ERROR] xrdp_process_main_loop: libxrdp_process_incoming failed
Feb 06 12:36:10 pi4-8 xrdp[394313]: [ERROR] xrdp_iso_send: trans_write_copy_s failed
Feb 06 12:36:10 pi4-8 xrdp[394313]: [ERROR] Sending [ITU T.125] DisconnectProviderUltimatum failed
```

There seems to be an issue with encryption (?) so I checked out the certificates and their privileges (through symlinks too) but they seem to be ok.
Due to my lack of knowledge, I am not able to troubleshoot any deeper than that.

BTW: a few weeks ago I tried the same thing on 32-bit bullseye installation with same result , but I haven't followed up because I decided to wait for the ARM64 release

Answer (score 2):

This helped me

sudo nano /etc/X11/xrdp/xorg.conf

## Find:

```
Option "DRMDevice" "/dev/dri/renderD128"
```

## Change to:

```
#Option "DRMDevice" "/dev/dri/renderD128"
Option "DRMDevice" ""
```

## Save and exit

sudo reboot

Comment: This 'works' but really slowed down screen refreshes to unusable for me. `sudo apt remove xrdp` then `sudo apt autoremove` followed by `sudo apt install xrdp` worked for me. Then I reversed the above recommendation (back to default) and it still works for me now.

Comment: @DeepSpace101 but why...

Answer (score 0):

lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Raspbian
Description:    Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
Release:        11
Codename:       bullseye

#####################################
User pi can not login into rdesktop !
#####################################

1)
make shure rdesktop is installed ...
sudo apt update
sudo apt install rdesktop

2)
create an other user then pi
example:

useradd newusername
pwd newusername
enter passsword - confirm password ...
sudo usermod -a -G newusername

sudo mkdir /home/newusername
cd /home
sudo chown newusername:newusername newusername
cd newusername
sudo mkdir Desktop
chown newusername:newusername Desktop

3)
after login get rid of annoying message:
"authentication-required-to-refresh-system-repositories"

sudo bash
cd /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d
nano 46-allow-update-repo.pkla

Insert into "6-allow-update-repo.pkla" :
-SNIP->
[Allow Package Management all Users]
Identity=unix-user:
Action=org.freedesktop.packagekit.system-sources-refresh
ResultAny=yes
ResultInactive=yes
ResultActive=yes
<-SNIP-

reboot and then RDP-Login with newusername !
done ...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I don't consider being forced to log in as a new user as a fix.
I've been doing a lot under login pi.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the setting in xorg.conf worked.
Except I still have the same problem that brought me to xrdp in the first place over VNC:
Slow Chromium.
And when I try suggestions that seem to speed up Chromium, then vPython renderings do not work.

So I installed FireFox which works pretty good by itself.
So then I launched vPython to show a sphere.   That of course opened Chromium, which got stuck to render the page.
So I copied the URL, pasted in FireFox and it worked great!

Now to figure out how to get vPython to launch FireFox instead of Chromium.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did:

- install xrdp

```
sudo apt install xrdp
```

- see if xrdp is running

```
systemctl show -p SubState --value xrdp`
sudo adduser xrdp ssl-cert
```

- remove myself from group render using vi (or your fav editor)

```
sudo vi /etc/group
```

- set screen size in /boot/config.txt (you can google for raspberry pi config.txt)

```
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=23
```

```
systemctl restart -p SubState --value xrdp
```

- One more thing - I have not discovered why, but... After rebooting I found a file named `/run/user/1000/bus` I renamed this file to `bus.old` and I set my display in `.bashrc`

```
DISPLAY=[hostname]:10.0
```

```
systemctl restart -p SubState --value xrdp
```