# xrdp and vnc problem on aarch64 bullseye

Tags: pi-4, vnc, 64-bit, xrdp

At first, there are something wrong of my xrdp, just as [XRDP on ARM64 bullseye issue](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/136043/xrdp-on-arm64-bullseye-issue?newreg=c439e6512ca940e998771e9b657c99f3) shows.

I tried Bram's method, and I can use 'windows remote desktop connect' properly. However, I find that I can't use VNC any more, it shows "Cannot currently show the desktop".

More seriously, after a power off of my raspberry 4B, I can use neither VNC nor XRDP.

VNC still shows "cannot currently show the desktop", and the XRDP shows “internal error has occurred, error code: 0x4"(this is translated), how can I fix at least one of them?

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple solution.

Don't use the Mutter WM, revert to X which VNC requires.

Enabling the in-built VNC server, should use Openbox rather than Mutter.

See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/135703/8697

`ps ax | grep openbox` should show if Openbox is in use.

NOTE I haven't tried 64 bit (because there is little point) but it this works on 32bit.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!I tried the `ps ax | grep openbox`, which shows `1153 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto openbox`. Is this meen Openbox is in use?
More seriously, after a power off of my raspberry, I can use neither VNC nor XRDP. VNC still shows "cannot currently show the desktop", and the XRDP shows “internal error has occurred, error code: 0x4"(this is translated), do you have any suggestions?

Comment: DO NOT put detail in Comments - edit your Question. But NO Mutter is in use.